# hibernate generates wrong create table DDL command for SAP HANA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate creates a table create statement without space before the keyword "comment" in all column definitions. As shown below.

This is with Hibernate 6.3.1-Final and the newest SAP HANA JDBC driver 2.17.12.

Hibernate: create column table KBDATA.IARTBZ (ARTMB decimal(34,0)comment 'Technisches Merkblatt', SPRCD decimal(34,0) not nullcomment 'Sprachcode', ARTB1 char(50)comment 'Bezeichnung 1', ARTB2 char(50)comment 'Bezeichnung 2', ARTBZ char(50)comment 'Bezeichnung', ARTES char(30)comment 'Eigenschaft', ARTET char(30)comment 'Effekt', ARTFT char(20)comment 'Farbton', ARTIA char(20)comment 'InnenAussen', ARTKN char(20)comment 'Körnung', ARTNA char(30)comment 'Artikel-Name', ARTNR char(5) not nullcomment 'Art.Nr.', ARTST char(30)comment 'Struktur', ARTZN char(30)comment 'Zusatzname', GLGRD char(15)comment 'Glanzgrad', primary key (SPRCD, ARTNR))

We tried also older versions of hibernate and the SAP HANA driver. To no avail.
When running the same Entity definition against MariaDB, the create table statement is created correctly (with a space before the "comment" keyword).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

having a look at the source in hibernate-core, the method getColumnComment in AbstractHANADialect.java misses a leading space.

As can be seen when comparing i.e against the code in MySQLDialect.java.

I have opened a pull request at hibernate.

```
MySQLDialect.java:
@Override
public String getColumnComment(String comment)
{
    return " comment '" + comment + "'";
}

AbstractHANADialect.java
@Override
public String getColumnComment(String comment)
{
    return "comment '" + comment + "'";
}
```